# Can't access data. object in another object?

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

This is the data in question

```js
[ 
    { 
        "id":1,
        "date":"2020-01-02",
        "start_time":"11:32:25",
        "end_time":"11:32:26",
        "editions":null,
        "coordinates":null,
        "ranking":null,
        "user_id":3,
        "instructor_id":2,
        "course_id":2,
        "package_id":null,
        "location_id":3,
        "created_at":null,
        "updated_at":null,
        "student_schedules":[ 
            { 
                "id":1,
                "student_schedule_id":1,
                "calification":75,
                "approved":0
            }
        ],
    }
]
```

I'm trying to get to calification in `student_schedules`. I've tried doing the following, the `history` is the entire data

```js
history.student_schedules['calification']

history.student_schedules.calification
```

This doesn't work and gives me errors

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'calification' of undefined
>
> [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'calification' of undefined"

I don't know why these errors are happening, the data is clearly there.

How can I access this data?

Comment: It's an array, so you would need to access it at the first position e.g. `history[0].student_schedules[0].calification;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`history` is an array of objects.

So you would first need to target the first object in the array with `history[0]`

Then, `student_schedules` is also an array of objects, so you have to do the same thing there and you end up with:

```
history[0].student_schedules[0].calification
```

You can tell the difference between an `object` and an `array` with `{}` and `[]` respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Both **history** and **student_schedules** are arrays which can contain multiple objects. If you want to access an object of an array you need to specify it's index, for example:

`history[0].student_schedules[0].clarification`

If the arrays will only contain one object then you can remove the `[]`

```
{ 
    "id":1,
    "date":"2020-01-02",
    "start_time":"11:32:25",
    "end_time":"11:32:26",
    "editions":null,
    "coordinates":null,
    "ranking":null,
    "user_id":3,
    "instructor_id":2,
    "course_id":2,
    "package_id":null,
    "location_id":3,
    "created_at":null,
    "updated_at":null,
    "student_schedules":
        { 
            "id":1,
            "student_schedule_id":1,
            "calification":75,
            "approved":0
        }
}
```

and then access the data like so:

`history.student_schedules.clarification`